# Assimp opengl load model vertices some values greater than 1

Tags: c++, opengl, assimp

I have the following code from learnopengl.com

```
void Model::load_model(string path)
{
        //read file via ASSIMP
        Assimp::Importer Importer;
        const aiScene* scene = Importer.ReadFile(path, aiProcess_Triangulate | aiProcess_FlipUVs);
        //check for errors
        if(!scene || scene->mFlags & AI_SCENE_FLAGS_INCOMPLETE || !scene->mRootNode)// if not zero
        {
                cout << "error, assimp ," << Importer.GetErrorString() << endl;
                return;
        }
        //retrieve the directory path of the filepath
        directory = path.substr(0, path.find_first_of('/'));
        process_node(scene->mRootNode, scene);
}
/*
 * Process a node in a recursive fashion . Process each individual mesh located at the node and repeat this process on its children nodes (if any)
 */
void Model::process_node(aiNode* node, const aiScene* scene)
{
        for( GLuint i = 0; i < node->mNumMeshes; i++ )
        {
                //the node object only contains indices to index the actual objects of the scene.
                //The scene contains all the data , node is just to keep stuff organized( like relations between nodes )
                aiMesh* mesh = scene->mMeshes[node->mMeshes[i]];
                meshes.push_back(process_mesh(mesh, scene));
        }
        //after we've processed all the meshes ( if any ) we then recusrsively process each of the children nodes 
        for(GLuint i = 0; i < node->mNumChildren; i++)
        {
                process_node(node->mChildren[i], scene);
        }
}
Mesh Model::process_mesh(aiMesh* mesh, const aiScene* scene)
{
        //data to fill
        vector<Mesh::Vertex> vertices;
        vector<GLuint> indices;
        vector<Mesh::Texture> textures;

        //walk through each of the meshes vertices
        for(GLuint i = 0; i < mesh->mNumVertices; i++)
        {
                Mesh::Vertex vertex;
                // we declare a placeholder vector since assimp uses its own vector class that doesn't directly convert to glm's vec3 class
                //so we transfter the data to this placeholder glm::vec3 first 
                glm::vec3 vector;
                //positions
                vector.x = mesh->mVertices[i].x; 
                vector.y = mesh->mVertices[i].y;
                vector.z = mesh->mVertices[i].z;
                vertex.position = vector;
                //normals
                vector.x = mesh->mNormals[i].x;
                vector.y = mesh->mNormals[i].y;
                vector.z = mesh->mNormals[i].z; ...
```

When I print out the first 20 values of `mesh->mVertices[i].x`  y and z I get some with values greater than 1 as show below

```
x1: 1.58967 Y1: -0.618526 z1: -0.683333
x1: 1.58939 Y1: -0.626895 z1: -0.681676
```

The obj file I am importing doesn't have any values greater than 1 and this is making the render fail. Where might the problem be?

Comment: Also can opengl render vertices whose values are greater than 1?

Comment: Doesn't look anything like C though :P

Comment: 3D models are not limited to any particular size. OpenGL also has no constraints on that. The only constraint it has is that vertices after projection have to be in the [-1, 1] range on all axis to be visible.

Comment: I have checked the 3D model again and yes there are values greater than 1 therefore the code above works as expected . Using renderdoc i have been able to see that the buffer contents for position end up with small figures like ```1.1204E-44``` . All the buffer contents have somehow been set to such small exponential figures.

Answer (score 1):

The positions of a model are related to its model coordinate system. So they can get bigger and less than 1, -1 or whatever. OpenGL is not limited to the range of [0 ... 1] for any values. So when your renderer needs the range from 0 to 1 you need to:

1. Find the min and max for your coordinates
2. Rescale all coordinates:

   float scale = 1.0/(max - min);
   foreach ( v : mesh.Vertices)
   v=v*scale;

Or rewrite your renderer that he is able to render arbitrary coorinate.